# Doubt regarding solving a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve a differential equation of the form:

$$f(r)\frac{dr}{dt}+g(r)\frac{d\theta}{dt}=h(r,\theta),$$

where $f(r)$, $g(r)$ and $h(r,\theta)$ are functions that are defined in terms of spherical coordinates. I require to solve the above equation and plot the variation of $\theta$ with $r$, i.e., the $r-\theta$ plot. However, I couldn't find a way to solve the differential equation. Any hints will be very helpful in this regard.

Comment: This is one differential equation for two unknown functions, are you sure there isn't meant to be a second differential equation along with it?

Comment: @Sal Yes, this is the only differential equation that I have.

Comment: In this case I do not think there can be a unique solution, as each choice of $d\theta/dt$ in the equation will lead to a different solution $r(\theta)$

Comment: @Sal One thing I forgot to mention that I am trying to solve the equation numerically. In that case, the problem is an IVP and so I need to specify initial values for $r$ and $\theta$.

Comment: Numerics will not help, as the problem is not well-posed. Suppose you specify the initial conditions $r(t_0)$ and $\theta(t_0)$. To find $r(t_1)$ and $\theta(t_1)$ (ie. the function values at the next time step) you must use the differential equation. But when you plug $r(t_0)$ and $\theta(t_0)$ into the DE, the values of $dr/dt$ and $d\theta/dt$ are not uniquely specified, so you cannot determine $r(t_1)$ and $\theta(t_1)$